Salesperson Lied about lease
I signed a lease a few weeks back thinking I was signing an application and then once I got approved then I would sign the actual lease which is how it was at my last apartment. The salesperson lied to be about me signing a final document, also lied about being able
subleasing is this grounds for breaking a lease?

You signed it
That means, legally, you read it and understood it.
Unless you can prove that you were placed under the misapprehension that it was only an application, you are legally bound. If the salesperson disagrees that they made such a statement, it will take more than your word that they did. Do you have other witnesses who can corroborate your version of events?
Note that I believe that you believe that you were only signing an application, but belief is not enough - you need evidence.

I agree. It would be a very hard case to win, and usually anything said prior to signing a document goes out the window when you sign a document and had an opportunity to read it, even if you didn't actually read it. You'd almost need to show that you were actively prevented from looking at the document you signed while being reassured about what it said and even that wouldn't be a sure thing.
